# .NET Data Caching Framework - How to cache data

Tags: c#, caching

Currently I'm writing a Web Application that needs to access the database quite often to retrieve records.

Now, I want to retrieve records and store them in the cache, and that's not a problem, but assume that I need to cache also in a Windows Application, what kind of object is best chosen then to do in-memory caching? IList<>, List<>, array, ...

So, in fact I would like to setup something general, and based on the type of application the appropriate type of object to store the items in will be choosed.

Comment: "I need to cache also in a Windows Application" seems to indicate that you want to do caching in an application that is not a web application. You should specify the type of application (WPF, Windows Service, whatever) and update the title of your post.

Comment: I have updated the title, and added a bit more information. I don't know wether or not data will be cached in a Windows application. I just want to make sure that my caching framework can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) namespace. Maybe it fits to your scenario.

Comment: It seems like that was the object I was searching for. Thanks.